# How to make Intellij highlight and collapse code (in your own language)?

Tags: intellij-idea, programming-languages

I'm making my own programming language. But now I want Intellij to highlight my new language and also - and that is very important for me - to collapse code blocks. What I mean by that is the following. Consider this example code:

```
if(1==1) {
    foo1();
    foo2();
}
```

in Intellij you can click on the side like in this picture here
[image: picture with collapse symbols in line 30 and 33]
in line 30 and 33.
And of course when you press them the code collapses to something like

```
if(1==1) {...}
```

so how to make Intellij do that with my new programming language?

Also any ideas how to make Intellij give me hints in a drop down menu, what my input might be and insert them when I press enter?
something like that here:

[image: example of drop down menu with hints]

Thank you for your help. Also partial answers or even small hints are warmly welcomed :)

Comment: You can try to implement a custom plugin for your language and extend `Code Folding` and `Code Completion` subsystems. Please see  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/folding-builder.html and https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/completion-contributor.html

Comment: If you encounter any problems during the plugin development please refer to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html